# How to capture string inside two curly braces with more curly braces inside string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a string like this:

> {{This a string `` `example{''} with my problem}}

and I need to capture a group like this:

> This a string `` `example{''} with my problem

I tried with this python code:

```
strLine = "{{This a string `` `example{''} with my problem}}"
pattern = "\{(.*?)\}"
strLine2 = re.search(pattern,strLine).group(1)
```

and always i get this output:

> {This a string `` `example{''

and with this regex expression:

```
pattern = "\{\{(.*?)\}\}"
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Can anybody help me? thanks in advance

Comment: Not reproducible for me too. https://paiza.io/projects/e/fcBzU9eAHU7a0DrcsERXbA?theme=twilight When pasting code, make sure that you [_Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: I'm so sorry, my error was in a previously If Statement, which checks if the string has a {{, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you're very close, you just need to add some more curly brackets:

`pattern = "\{{(.*?)\}}"`

This way your match group will match everything either side of 2 x curly brackets whereas previously you were only doing that for either side of 1 x curly bracket, hence it starting after the penultimate one on the left and ending at the one just after example.

You can also condense your regex to:

`"{{(.*?)}}"`